# PHP Displaying an email in browser

Tags: php, email, html-email

I have stored in a database an email in its original format (including the headers and the multipart info). I want to display the text/html of the message. How can I parse the message and just display the html text?

Comment: Can you post an example of the email?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TPw3uUA6

Comment: This particular threat have good information and code, i suggest you to check it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616762/extract-body-from-raw-email-with-regex

Comment: [php-mime-mail-parser](http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/), [mailReader.php](http://stuporglue.org/mailreader-php-parse-e-mail-and-save-attachments-php-version-2/) and [Mail Parse Function Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mailparse.php)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display unaltered text from email in text format you can use `<PRE></PRE>` tags

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it...

```
$emailArray = file($someFileName);
$count = count ($emailArray);
$divider = false;
$emailText = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if (strpos($emailArray[$i], 'Content-Type: text/html') !== false){
        $divider = $emailArray[$i - 1];
    }elseif ($divider && strpos($emailArray[$i], $divider . '--') === false){
        $emailText .= $emailArray[$i];
    }elseif(strpos($emailArray[$i], $divider) !== false){
        break;
    }
}
echo $emailText;
```